# Creating a signal with parameters in PyQt

Tags: pyqt4

I am using the following example

```
class bar(QObject):
    def mySlot(self,p):
        print "This is my slot " + str(p)


class Foo(QObject):
    trigger = pyqtSignal()

    def my_connect_and_emit_trigger(self):
        self.trigger.emit(12)

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.
        print "trigger signal received"


b = bar()
a = Foo()
a.trigger.connect(int,b.mySlot) <---how to fix this
a.connect_and_emit_trigger()
```

I am trying to attach the slot `b.mySlot`which takes one int parameter to a signal `a.trigger` my question is what am I doing wrong. I could not find any material that helps with parameters of signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is correct:

```
class bar(QObject):
    def mySlot(self,p):
        print "This is my slot " + str(p)


class Foo(QObject):
    trigger = pyqtSignal(int)

    def my_connect_and_emit_trigger(self):
        self.trigger.emit(12)

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.
        print "trigger signal received"


b = bar()
a = Foo()
a.trigger.connect(b.mySlot)
a.my_connect_and_emit_trigger()
```

Doc is [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)